# Unity 3D Attaching Score Display Script to prefab

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I was following Unity 3d tutorial on the Learn Unity website, but here is the thing I wanted to do things a bit differently. It worked out well at start but in the end this turned out to be a bad decision and now I manually need to attach the script to every pickable object.

Here is my code:
Note: What it does is rotate the Pickups and display the score when the pickups collide with player ball.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PickUps : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 Rotate;
    private int Score;
    public Text ScoreGUI;

    private void Start()
    {
        Rotate = new Vector3(0, 25, 0);
        Score = 0;
        DisplayScore();

    }
    void Update () {
        transform.Rotate(Rotate*Time.deltaTime);
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Ball"))
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            Score = Score + 1;
            DisplayScore();
        }
    }
    void DisplayScore()
    {
        ScoreGUI.text = "SCORE " + Score.ToString();
    }
}
```

Problem:

It works yes but I need to manually attach the text (under canvas) to every pickup object which is exhausting and not a good thing to do.

What I want To achieve:

Like in the tutorials mostly they use prefabs in this kind of work (I think), problem is I can attach the text to the pickups (objects/biscuits) in the current scene but I cannot drag and attach the text To the prefab of biscuits I made the text just wont attach in its blank for "Text".

Comment: Can you not drag the Text component of the prefab into the ScoreGUI field of your prefab?

Comment: Every PickUp has it's own Text? Or all of them use the same Text?

Comment: @FredrikWiderberg No I Cant Do That.

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge No The Text is the Score when I destroy or disable the Pick Up the Text should Update See The Images please it https://imgur.com/a/qp7Umpq

Comment: You can't assign Scene objects to a prefab's fields because when it gets instantiated, that object may not exist. You might say "of course it will exist!" But here's the thing: *Unity doesn't know that and cannot know that.*

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change the score `Text` directly. Use a `Controller` to make the bridge instead. I would do something like this:

Put this script somewhere in your scene:

```
public class ScoreManager : Singleton<ScoreManager>
{
    private int score = 0;

    // Event that will be called everytime the score's changed
    public static Action<int> OnScoreChanged; 

    public void SetScore(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
        InvokeOnScoreChanged();
    }

    public void AddScore(int score)
    {
        this.score += score;
        InvokeOnScoreChanged();
    }

    // Tells to the listeners that the score's changed
    private void InvokeOnScoreChanged()
    {
        if(OnScoreChanged != null)
        {
            OnScoreChanged(score);
        }
    }
}
```

This script attached in the `Text` game object:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Text))]
public class ScoreText : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Text scoreText;

    private void Awake()
    {
        scoreText = GetComponent<Text>();
        RegisterEvents();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        UnregisterEvents();
    }

    private void RegisterEvents()
    {
        // Register the listener to the manager's event 
        ScoreManager.OnScoreChanged += HandleOnScoreChanged; 
    }

    private void UnregisterEvents()
    {
        // Unregister the listener
        ScoreManager.OnScoreChanged -= HandleOnScoreChanged;
    }

    private void HandleOnScoreChanged(int newScore)
    {
        scoreText.text = newScore.ToString();
    }
}
```

And in your PickUps class:

```
void DisplayScore()
{
    ScoreManager.Instance.SetScore(Score); // Maybe what you need is AddScore to not 
                                           // reset the value everytime
}
```

A simple singleton you can use (you can find more complete ones on the internet):

```
public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    static T instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));

                if (instance == null) Debug.LogError("Singleton of type " + typeof(T).ToString() + " not found in the scene.");
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

But **be careful**, the singleton pattern can be a shot in the foot if not used correctly. You should only it them moderately for managers.